# Printing SQL output in filename iteratively

Tags: python

I am trying to pull data from a database store each record in its own text file. To properly name the text files, I would like to write the file name as the ID of the record stored in the database. How would I adjust the following code to do that?

```
    cur.execute("select postid, flatcontent from openscattachments where hasattachment is not null order by postid;")
    for i, row in enumerate(cur):
        with open('{}.txt'.format(i), 'w') as f:
        f.write('{}'.format(row))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can unpack the tuples returned by `cur` directly instead of using `enumerate`.

```
sql = "select postid, flatcontent from openscattachments where hasattachment is not null order by postid;"
cur.execute(sql)

for (postid, flatcontent) in cur:
    with open('{}.txt'.format(postid), 'w') as f:
    f.write('{}'.format(row))
```